# Prevent RecycleView from scrolling when onTouchEvent() is called in custom view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

How to prevent RecycleView from scrolling when `onTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent)` is called in custom view that is part of recycle view item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there are no quick solution.

Register touch listener in your custom view.

```
customView.setOnTouchListener { v, event ->
            when (event.action) {
                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    callback?.onStartTrackingTouch()
                }
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    callback?.onStopTrackingTouch()
                }
                else -> {}
            }
            super.onTouchEvent(event)
        }
```

Register callback in adapter:

```
callback = object : CustomView.Callback {
                
                override fun onStartTrackingTouch() {
                    enableRecycleViewScroll(false)                   
                }

                override fun onStopTrackingTouch() {
                    enableRecycleViewScroll(true)
                }
            }
```

Create function inside adapter(you can get reference to `RecycleView` in `onAttachedToRecyclerView()` function):

```
private fun enableRecycleViewScroll(enable: Boolean) {
        recyclerView?.apply {
            val layoutManager = layoutManager as CustomLayoutManager
            layoutManager.enableScroll = enable
        }
    }
```

And create custom layout manager:

```
    open class CustomLayoutManager(
    context: Context?, spanCount: Int, orientation: Int, reverseLayout: Boolean
) : LinearLayoutManager(context, spanCount, orientation, reverseLayout) {

    var enableScroll = true

    override fun canScrollVertically(): Boolean {
        return enableScroll
    }
}
```